# How can i set one javascript function to work on multiple html select elements

Tags: javascript, html, function

JavaScript
So i have this function thats used to play back audio to users when the select the

```
function initAudio(){
    var audio, dir, ext, mynoteslist;
    dir = "audio/";
    ext = ".mp3";
    // Audio Object
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = dir+"a3"+ext;
    audio.play();
    // Event Handling
    mynoteslist = document.getElementById("mynoteslist");
    mynoteslist.addEventListener("change", changeNote);
    // Functions
    function changeNote(event){
        audio.src = dir+event.target.value+ext;
        audio.play();
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudio);
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <select class="mynoteslist" id=mynoteslist>
      <option value="A1">A1</option>
      <option value="B1">B1</option>
      <option value="C1">C1</option>
      <option value="D1">D1</option>
      <option value="E1">E1</option>
      <option value="F1">F1</option>
      <option value="G1">G1</option>
    </select>

    <select class="mynoteslist1" id=mynoteslist1>
      <option value="A1">A1</option>
      <option value="B1">B1</option>
      <option value="C1">C1</option>
      <option value="D1">D1</option>
      <option value="E1">E1</option>
      <option value="F1">F1</option>
      <option value="G1">G1</option>
    </select>


<script src="Tune.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="Notes.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
```

Im having trouble setting the function to work on multiple select elements.
i tried changing the code to something like this

```
// Event Handling
    //mynoteslist = document.getElementById("mynoteslist");
    /mynoteslist.addEventListener("change", changeNote);

    var arr = document.getElementsByClassname("mynoteslist");
    for (var k=0; k<arr.length; k++){
       arr[k].addEventListener("change", changeNote);
}
```

Which isnt really working for me.

Comment: *"Which isnt really working for me."* What happens instead?

Comment: The change you made is the correct thing to do. In what way is it not really working? Does *anything* happen? Are errors logged in the console? *edit* yes what the next comment says

Comment: the class of your second list is mynoteslist1 and not mynoteslist, so it is not selected.

Comment: Do you get an error in the version with `getElementsByClassname`?

Comment: The function is named `getElementsByClassName`, with a capital `N`.

Comment: I can see forward slash on line 3, I don't think it suppose to be there.

Comment: Oh it was because i had no capital N.
Silly me sorry.
Thankyou